# Как убрать расстояние между bar в recharts

Tags: javascript, frontend

[image: Нужно убрать расстояние между 2мя bar]

Как убрать расстояние между двумя столбцами в библиотеке recharts

Comment: Картинка? забудь про картинки на stack overflow, в данном случаи и 95% случаев от нее 0 пользы, только скриншоты, если там нет кода, если код то собственно его и кидай, через codepen или подобные если кода очень много. Скинь ссылку на эту библиотеку, скинь ссылку на компонент который ты оттуда используешь, предоставь больше информации. Никто не полезет разбираться с библиотекой которую не использовал, ради того чтобы тебе помочь.

Comment: и в тэгах укажи библиотеку

Comment: Я просто работаю в месте где у меня нет возможности сделать скриншот и выложить его, в тегах нельзя указать библиотеку, потому что её нет в доступных тегах на stack overflow, а чтобы добавить новый у меня не хватает прав